# Key wrapping with an ECDH public key?

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve

Preface:  I don't know whether it's more appropriate to ask this question here or on the Crypto site.  Feel free to move or delete or whatever the appropriate SE action is.

---

I've been asked to help update some encryption software.  Broadly speaking, the software already does the following steps, none of which are particularly unusual.  I've left out the error handling and `Provider` arguments for simplicity of posting:

1) Generates a random symmetric secret key for use with AES-128 (or AES-256, *mutatis mutandis*):

```
KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keygen.init (128, a_SecureRandom_instance);
SecretKey sessionKey = keygen.generateKey();
```

2) Wraps the symmetric secret key, depending on whether the user is using...
2a) ...an RSA public key from a keypair:

```
// OAEP wasn't used in this software for hysterical raisins
Cipher wrapper = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
wrapper.init (Cipher.WRAP_MODE, user_RSA_PublicKey);
```

2b) ...a passphrase:

```
SecretKey stretched = ...passphrase stretched through a PBKDF like bcrypt...;
// I don't remember whether it's specified as "AES" or "AESWrap" here
Cipher wrapper = Cipher.getInstance("AES or AESWrap/ECB/NoPadding");
wrapper.init (Cipher.WRAP_MODE, stretched);
```

2c) Either route, the session key is wrapped:

```
byte[] wrapped = wrapper.wrap(sessionKey);
```

3) The session key is used to create a `Cipher` using `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE` along with a random IV, and then shedloads of data are run through it.  That part is pretty standard but I can post it if you really want to see `CipherInputStream` usage.  The wrapped session key is stored along with the encrypted data and a bunch of HMACs of everything under the sun.

Later at decryption time, the user provides either the RSA private key, or the passphrase for stretching; the software unwraps the symmetric key and decrypts the data.

All of that has been working for some time.  But of course RSA keypairs are getting big and slow, so they'd like to support an additional possibility for step #2 above, in which the public keys are generated using an elliptic curve algorithm (P384 ECDH is the usual case).  And this is where we're getting confused.

There doesn't seem to be a JCE replacement algorithm/transformation for elliptic curves in the `Cipher wrapper = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")` invocation.  The only one listed in the Java documentation is "ECIES", which seems(?) to be aimed more towards multiple party key agreement?

All of the APIs that I can find for the Java builtin JCE, or even looking over Bouncy Castle, only mention ECDH keys in the context of key agreement and transport, where they're used to *generate* a symmetric secret key instead of *wrapping* an existing one.

I feel we're missing something here, possibly because of poor assumptions.  Is `Cipher.wrap()` genuinely not an option with ECDH keys?  Or it *is*, but we need to do something funky in order to create the ECIES `Cipher` instance?

Comment: If you are going to full upgrade, could you tell the restrictions, risks, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSA is an algorithm (or depending on how you look at it, two very similar but distinct algorithms) for encryption and signature. RSA encryption can encrypt dat which is a (lower-level) key, in which case it is called wrapping.

**DH is a key agreement algorithm**, in both its classical (aka integer, Zp, modp, or finite-field/FF) form and its elliptic-curve form (ECDH). Note that at least for classic DH the raw agreement value g^a^b mod n = g^b^a mod n has enough mathematical structure people aren't comfortable using it directly as a key, so we run it through a key derivation function, abbreviated KDF. It's not clear to me that ECDH values really need KDF, at least for the commonly used X9/NIST curves including P384 (you might look or ask on crypto.SX if you care), but using a KDF is cheap and well-established so we do so.

I've never heard anyone competent call (EC)DH key transport, because it is specifically NOT. It *is* included in key *exchange*, a term created to cover the (useful) union of transport and agreement.

You can create an **encryption scheme *using* (EC)DH** by using the agreed (and derived) value as the key for symmetric encryption -- and that ***is* (EC)IES.** I don't know what made you think IES is something else. Modern practice is that the symmetric encryption should be authenticated, and the standardized forms of IES as a separate scheme use CBC encryption with HMAC authentication, although you could validly design a scheme that uses e.g. GCM instead.

As you saw, the BouncyCastle provider provides implementations of DH (classic) or EC IES "with{AES,DESEDE}-CBC" (in versions before 1.56 the -CBC was sometimes omitted) which use KDF2 from P1363a with SHA1, the indicated CBC cipher, and HMAC-SHA1. The 'standard' (Sun/Oracle/Open) providers do not, but you can combine the raw agreement operation, the KDF, plus symmetric encryption and MAC to produce the same result.

This is similar (though different in some details) to the operation of [CMS-formerly-PKCS7 with classic DH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3370#section-4.1) [and ECDH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5753#section-3.1) and [PGP with ECDH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6637#section-8). (PGP does not support classic DH; it used ElGamal encryption instead as the alternative to RSA.) Not to mention TLS (sometimes through 1.2, always in 1.3) and SSH which use either classic or EC DH 'exchange' (here interactive, and usually ephemeral-ephemeral instead of having at least the receiver static) to produce a secret which is derived and used as key material for symmetric encryption with authentication of the data.

Comment: _I don't know what made you think IES is something else._  I don't actively think it *is* "anything else" because I didn't know what it's supposed to be in the first place.  Primarily because I've not encountered the term anywhere else, Oracle offers zero documentation on how to use it with their standard JCE API, and I can find scant examples of anybody else using `getInstance("ECIES")` from which to learn.  But I'll take your suggestion of using the public keys to generate the symmetric session key, and see whether we can make it work.  Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme gives the basic idea, which is that it uses DH-created key material for symmetric (authenticated) encryption. Oracle documents (at least somewhat) the algorithms _supported by Oracle providers_, which IES is NOT. I'll admit Bouncy tends not to have much more than the minimal javadoc (class/method/field names and types). Good luck.

Comment: Heh, we've given up on getting any of the EC functionality working with the existing encryption scheme already implemented as shown above; the approaches are just too damned different in their requirements, their starting points, and how they handle multiple keys.  The Oracle JCE API has too many assumptions baked in, none of the error messages make sense, and we can't find published documentation.  If we ever adopt EC it'll have to be a rewrite from the beginning.  Thanks for your time anyhow!